# How will my wordpress plugin know who the student is with the user account and how will I be able to show the additional information?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm pretty new to making wordpress plugins and I've been trying to make a plugin that manages reviews for student. In the CMS of wordpress I made the CRUD for adding reviews. Now I'm trying to log a student in and make sure he sees his own reviews on the website.

I've been getting this **error:**

> Fatal error:
>   Call to a member function getDagopdracht() on null in
>   D:\xammp\htdocs\ivs_website_kopie\wp-content\plugins\ivs-dagopdracht\includes\views\view_resultaat.php
>   on line 34

I think this is because the website doesn't know what id it is.
I know the person I currently logged in has student_id 4 and ID(wordpress) 4.
But when I try to put in 4 it gives me the same error.

This the website code in view_resultaat.php:

```
// Create instance Beoordelinggeven class
$beoordelinggeven_class = new BeoordelingGeven();

?>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Resultaten (BETA)</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Dagopdracht</th>
                        <th>Beoordeling</th>
                        <th>Commentaar</th> 
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <?php

                $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
                if ($user_id == 0) {
                    echo 'You are currently not logged in.';
                    } else {

                    $leerling_id = $beoordelinggeven_class->getLeerlingIdByUserId($nummer, $user_id);


                    //view beoordelinggeven
                    $beoordelinggeven_objects = $beoordelinggeven_class->getBeoordelingLeerling($nummer, $user_id);
                    //if(leerling id){
                    foreach ($beoordelinggeven_objects as $id => $beoordelinggeven_object) {
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>' . $beoordelinggeven_object->getDagopdracht() . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $beoordelinggeven_object->getBeoordeling() . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>' . $beoordelinggeven_object->getComment() . '</td>';
                        ?>

                        <?php
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                    } 
                    //}
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <td><a href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>">Terug</a></td>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the function it corresponds to in file BeoordelingGeven.php:

```
public function getLeerlingIdByUserId($nummer, $user_id){

    global $wpdb;
   echo $user_id;
    $id_query = "SELECT l.`nummer`, u.`ID`, d.`naam` d_naam, b.`naam` b_naam, g.`comment` FROM `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_beoordeling` g 
        INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_dagopdracht` d ON g.`beoordeling_dagopdracht` = d.`dagopdracht_id`
        INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_leerlingen` l ON g.`beoordeling_leerling` = l.`nummer`
        INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_beoordeling_type` b ON g.`beoordeling_beoordeling` = b.`beoordeling_id`
        INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_users` u ON l.`leerling_user_id` = u.`ID`
        WHERE l.nummer = $nummer AND u.ID = $user_id";

     $id = $wpdb->get_results($id_query);
     print_r($id);
    return $id;
}

public function getBeoordelingLeerling($nummer, $user_id) {

global $wpdb;

$query = "SELECT l.`nummer`, u.`ID`, d.`naam` d_naam, b.`naam` b_naam, g.`comment` FROM `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_beoordeling` g 
        INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_dagopdracht` d ON g.`beoordeling_dagopdracht` = d.`dagopdracht_id`
        INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_leerlingen` l ON g.`beoordeling_leerling` = l.`nummer`
        INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_beoordeling_type` b ON g.`beoordeling_beoordeling` = b.`beoordeling_id`
        INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_users` u ON l.`leerling_user_id` = u.`ID`
        WHERE l.nummer = $nummer AND u.ID = $user_id";

$result_array = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A);
//"WHERE d.dagopdracht_id = $id";
// For all database results:
$result = $result_array[self::RESULT_ARRAY_OFFSET];

// For all database results:
$this->setDagopdracht($result['beoordeling_dagopdracht']);
$this->setBeoordeling($result ['beoordeling_beoordeling']);
$this->setComment($result['comment']);


return $this;
```

}

What am I missing?

This is my very first question here, sorry if I made any mistakes.

Additional this is my database:
student table
[image: student]

user table
[image: user]

reviews
[image: reviews]

Comment: Seems like you're missing "beoordeling_dagopdracht" in your SQL query.

Comment: Are you keeping student data in a different database sheet, not the default ones? If yes, then I think you chose the hard way to use WP (OK, sometimes it's a must). I think you would be better off, if you changed to custom fields and standard / default query functions.

Comment: If I run my query in sql it gives the correct output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working it seems one of the functions wasn't correctly written.
Mainly the last part of getBeoordelingLeerling().

```
public function getLeerlingIdByUserId($user_id) {

    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT nummer FROM `wp_ivs_leerlingen` WHERE leerling_user_id = $user_id";
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    $id = $result[0]->nummer;

    return $id;
}

public function getBeoordelingLeerling($nummer) {

    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT l.`nummer`, d.`naam` d_naam, b.`naam` b_naam, g.`comment` FROM `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_beoordeling` g 
            INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_dagopdracht` d ON g.`beoordeling_dagopdracht` = d.`dagopdracht_id`
            INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_leerlingen` l ON g.`beoordeling_leerling` = l.`nummer`
            INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_beoordeling_type` b ON g.`beoordeling_beoordeling` = b.`beoordeling_id`
            WHERE l.nummer = $nummer";

    $result_array = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A);
    //"WHERE d.dagopdracht_id = $id";
    // For all database results:
    foreach ($result_array as $idx => $array) {

        // New object
        $bl = new BeoordelingGeven();
        // Set all info
        $bl->setId($array['beoordeling_geven_id']);
        $bl->setDagopdracht($array['d_naam']);
        $bl->setBeoordeling($array['b_naam']);
        $bl->setComment($array['comment']);
        // Add new object to return array.
        $return_array[] = $bl;
    }
    return $return_array;
}
```

Now I get all the information I need :). Thank you for all the tips, and thank you sheetal for sticking with me.

Answer (score 1):

To get the current user id you can use this code snippet:

```
<?php
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $user_id = $current_user->ID;
?>
```

Let's make this code simple

view--

```
<?php
   $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
   if ($user_id == 0) {
    echo 'You are currently not logged in.';
    } else {

        $nummer = $beoordelinggeven_class->getLeerlingIdByUserId($user_id);
        //view beoordelinggeven
        $beoordelinggeven_objects = $beoordelinggeven_class->getBeoordelingLeerling($nummer, $user_id);
        //if(leerling id){
        foreach ($beoordelinggeven_objects as $id => $beoordelinggeven_object) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $beoordelinggeven_object->getDagopdracht() . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $beoordelinggeven_object->getBeoordeling() . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $beoordelinggeven_object->getComment() . '</td>';
        ?>

        <?php
        echo '</tr>';
        }
    } 
    //}
    ?>
```

BeoordelingGeven.php-----

```
public function getLeerlingIdByUserId($user_id){

    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT `nummer` FROM `wp_ivs_beoordeling` WHERE leerling_user_id = $user_id;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    print_r($result);
    $id = $result[0]->nummer;
    echo $id;
    return $id;
}

public function getBeoordelingLeerling($nummer, $user_id) {

    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT l.`nummer`, u.`ID`, d.`naam` d_naam, b.`naam` b_naam, g.`comment` FROM `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_beoordeling` g 
            INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_dagopdracht` d ON g.`beoordeling_dagopdracht` = d.`dagopdracht_id`
            INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_leerlingen` l ON g.`beoordeling_leerling` = l.`nummer`
            INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_beoordeling_type` b ON g.`beoordeling_beoordeling` = b.`beoordeling_id`
            INNER JOIN `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_users` u ON l.`leerling_user_id` = u.`ID`
            WHERE l.nummer = $nummer AND u.ID = $user_id";

    $result_array = $wpdb->get_results( $query, ARRAY_A);
    //"WHERE d.dagopdracht_id = $id";
    // For all database results:
    $result = $result_array[self::RESULT_ARRAY_OFFSET];

    // For all database results:
    $this->setDagopdracht($result['beoordeling_dagopdracht']);
    $this->setBeoordeling($result ['beoordeling_beoordeling']);
    $this->setComment($result['comment']);


    return $this;
}
```

Comment: So I did the code snippet and he does give back 4 thats correct, but he doesn't seem to know what student is linked to the user but I do have a foreign key from the user table in the student table in the database.

Comment: you can fetch the student id by using user_id [foreign key] from db

Comment: "SELECT leerling_id FROM student_table WHERE user_id = 4" ---- you can get the student id like this.

Comment: Ok so I got this now.
$query = "SELECT `leerling_id` FROM `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_dg_leerling` WHERE user_id = $user_id";

Comment: How do I get this query to the database now as an order?

Comment: you want this select query as an order? can you please explain

Comment: Well I need to be able to use this query to get de student id. how do I mingle this with the current code I have I have a huge inner join atm for the reviews. my idea is to get the reviews by ->user(user_id)->student(student_id)->reviews(student_id)

Comment: You can create a new function which would contain this query and return the student id

Comment: and then just call that function where you want to use the student id

Comment: I will try this! you'll hear from me.

Comment: It seems I made it worse now he says:

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getLeerlingId() on null in D:\xammp\htdocs\ivs_website_kopie\wp-content\plugins\ivs-dagopdracht\includes\views\view_resultaat.php on line 34

Comment: did you created the function in the same file where getBeoordelingLeerling() is created?

Comment: correct. its the function above gebeoordelingleerling.

Comment: my gui and database are seperate files.

Comment: please check if your object class is working properly or not

Comment: hey are you getting the user_id in the same function or passing the id to it?

Comment: where is get_current_user_id(); ?

Comment: you need to get the current user like this - $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $user_id = $current_user->ID; then call the function further

Comment: I updated my code once again and now when I include the user_id when asking for the student id it says that user_id is NULL but leerling id 1? this is not correct it should be 4 and 4, dunno where he gets 1.

Comment: am I maybe in need of a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: with a left join he gives 4 and 2.

Comment: what is the current user id?

Comment: the user Id im logged into is ID->4 and leerling_id->4

Comment: yes it does, but when I echo the student id it gives a 1 or a 2 which is incorrect it should be 4 aswell.

Comment: what is this- `wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db`.`wp_ivs_dg_leerling` ? is it your table name, i think just select `leerling_id` for check and instead of echo $id use print_r($id);

Comment: wp_ivs_dagopdracht_db.wp_ivs_dg_leerling is databasename.tablename, when I try to select only leerling id it says NULL even when I run it in the database however when I select leerling id and user id it says user_id NULL and leerling id 4

Comment: do one thing just use SELECT * FROM ~  instead of leerling_id and then print_r the result and check what happens

Comment: if I select all from the student table it gives me all.

Comment: he gives back the int 4, since there are 4 entires in there. does this mean he gives the amount back? because he gives 2 back for student->4 user->4

Comment: you are running $wpdb->query($id_query); in place of this query use $wpdb->get_results($id_query); and you'll get the user_id

Comment: [0] => stdClass Object ( [nummer] => 1 [leerling_user_id] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [nummer] => 4 [leerling_user_id] => 4 )

Comment: those are indeed the 2 I need. But now I need to get those reviews with nummer. btw I switched (leerling_id -> nummer) and (user_id -> leerling_user_id), orders from my senior programmer.

Comment: is there only one student with that user id? and what is nummer here?

Comment: I renamed student_id to nummer and yes only one student can have that ID.

Comment: okay but now it should work and are you sure about the one user id in database?

Comment: yes I know, that he knows which id is with which id now I just need to make a huge inner join to get all the info I need.

Comment: okay..then just login with different user id and check the result

Comment: welp seems he does know the correct ID, however I still get the same fatal error :/

Comment: Ive updated my code once again with the new names, I highlighted the keys and foreign keys red is a student and blue is a student.

Comment: you haven't defined $nummer in your view thats' why you are getting the error $beoordelinggeven_class->getLeerlingIdByUserId([$nummer ??], $user_id);

Comment: and i don't understand if you'll send nummer from your view as a parameter to the function then for which thing are you using you  function because nummer is what you'll get using the function

Comment: hey let's make your code simple...i worked on it on my end it's working all fine

Comment: it gives back an empty Array() for me with the same error.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `wp_ivs_leerlingen` WHERE leerling_user_id = $user_id when I do "SELECT nummer FROM `wp_ivs_leerlingen` WHERE leerling_user_id = $user_id"; it fails and gives NULL

Comment: I got it the function getBeoordelingLeerling() was wronlgy written :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if ($user_id == 0) {
    echo 'You are currently not logged in.';
} else {
    echo 'You are logged in as user '.$user_id;
}
```

[MORE DETAIL LINK](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_current_user_id)

Comment: he says I am logged in as user 4 which is correct but he doesnt correspond to the student that is linked to it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link and you can get all details of the logged-in user
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user